# Elasticsearch array format for multiple must terms

Tags: php, arrays, elasticsearch

I'm working on elasticsearch (2.3) and am trying to create a search query. For elasticsearch I need JSON, but I start with a simple php array and encode it to JSON afterwards.

I have a problem with creating the right array format.

This is a small part of the code I'm using:

```
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must']["term"]['pprCategories']= "category1";
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must_not']['exists']['field'] = "field1";
```

With an if statement I add a new line:

```
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must']['term']['country_name']= "country1";
```

So the total code is:

```
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must']["term"]['pprCategories']= "category1";
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must_not']['exists']['field'] = "field1";
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must']['term']['country_name']= "country1";

#output
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_encode($params, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
echo "</pre>";
```

The is the actual result I get from the query I built:

```
{
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            "term": {
                                "pprCategories": "category1",
                                "country_name": "country1"
                            }
                        },
                        "must_not": {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "field1"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the desired result would be as follows, i.e. with two elements in the `bool/must` array:

```
{
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "filtered": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "pprCategories": "category1"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "country_name": "country1"
                }
              }
            ],
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "field1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the `bool/must` array contains two conditions instead of just one: pprCategories and country_name are two different 'must' conditions.

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: To me it doesn't make any sense to have `must` twice.. so the desired result is invalid

Comment: Your JSON (in the value of the key `bool`) has 2 keys with the same name: `must` - json object cannot have it.

Comment: @DavidWinder Okay, clear. I have 2 (or more) values on which elasticsearch 2.3 must match (versus should match). Any idea how to create the JSON request?

Comment: @deceze the question is pretty clear, not sure why you're closing it.

Comment: _I have 2 (or more) values on which elasticsearch ..._ No idea what you are talking about. please open a new question

Comment: @Val The expected result is nonsense, sooo… ‍♂️ pretty unclear what the answer could possibly be.

Comment: @deceze agreed, though 5dale5 seems novice at ES and hence doesn't really know how his DSL, that's why his expected result is wrong. But, personally I got exactly what his issue was, but now can't answer ;-)

Comment: @Val I'd be happy if you'd rephrase the question away from the "array issue" and towards something focusing on ES DSL.

Comment: @B001ᛦ I will. I direct the question more to ES. Thanks anyway all.

Comment: @Val Thanks for getting me ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add several conditions, you need to understand that `bool/must` should be an array. You can make your code work like this:

```
// first create the bool/must array with a single term condition
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'] = [ 
   [ 
     'term' => [
        'pprCategories' => "category1"; 
     ]
   ] 
];
// add the must_not condition
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must_not']['exists']['field'] = "field1";

// test your condition
if (...) {
    // now add a second constraint to the bool/must array
    $params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][] = [ 
        'term' => [
            'country_name' => "country1" 
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: In this case, the output would be:
   ` "must": [ { "term": { "pprCategories": "category1" }  },  { "term": { "country_name": "country1"  }  }  ], "must_not": {  "exists": {  "exists": {  "field": "field1"   }`. So an array at term... not working

Comment: That's the only way to add several must constraints on different fields. Try the query please, and report. Also note that you have `exists` twice, so something else must be wrong in the way you build the query

Comment: Yes, had only just to test it. It works! Elasticsearch accepts it this way. Other solution is similar to @LuisLeonGonzalez and works bij adding lines like `$params1['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][]["term"]['pprCategories']= "category1";` Problem solved! Thanks all!

Comment: Cool, glad we figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be going this way before taking it to json.

```
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][0]["term"]['pprCategories']= "category1";
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][1]["term"]['country_name']= "country1";
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][2]["term"]['population_name']= "population1";
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][3]["term"]['kilometers_amount']= "55145";
```

Comment: The array must be at the `must` level not the `term` one